# my code does not run with the index.js file only with index.mjs > Node.js

Tags: node.js

good guys I'm still learning and since I'm facing this type of error, I don't know what to do for the code to accept calling as index.js, should I be worried about that? all files i have to change the file to "index.mjs" to work correctly. what I would like to know is if I should accept this or do I have to fix it to run as index.js could you tell me if there is a problem with everything being in mjs?

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
const chalk = require('chalk')

inquirer.prompt([
    {name: "p1", message: `${chalk.green("what is your first name: ")}`},
    {name: "p2", message: `${chalk.green("what is years old: ")}`}
])
.then((answers) => {
    console.log(`${chalk.yellow(answers.p1, answers.p2)}`)
    const infoName = answers.p1
    const infoAge = answers.p2
    
    console.log(`his name is ${chalk.red(infoName)} and your age is ${chalk.red(infoAge)} years old`)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

this is the error that appears when I try to run with the index.js file

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Odin\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\nodejs tarefas\Fundamentos\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js from C:\Users\Odin\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\nodejs tarefas\Fundamentos\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of inquirer.js in C:\Users\Odin\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\nodejs tarefas\Fundamentos\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Odin\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\nodejs tarefas\Fundamentos\index.js:1:18) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

baixei a versão mais recente,

Comment: You could alternatively do what the error told you and use dynamic `import()`, but it's right that using modules and static `import` is easier. But instead of renaming all files you could also set `type: "module"` in your package.json

Comment: thank you I will continue using MJS, with time I will have more experience and I will see other ways to use it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `inquirer` is a *pure-ESM* package.

**What is ESM?**

Node.js appeared long before import/export support in JS. So it's used (and still is) so called require.js for imports.
Later, Node.js added support for [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), but with some limitations. One of these limitations is that ESM script can only be imported from another ESM script.

**What to do?**

1. The Node.js ecosystem is slowly migrating to the ESM. So you can continue using ESM, but you should avoid using `require` and use `import` instead. E.g.:

```
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
```

2. If you want to use `require`, you have to downgrade `inquirer` to version 8+
3. You can also use TypeScript with [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) and always use import/export.

Comment: "One of these limitations is that ESM script can only be imported from another ESM script." - That's not true, you can use `await import(...)` from CommonJS too, the limitation is just that `import` is needed and not `require`, and that may complicate code because `import` is asynchronous.